# Is there a way to find out how many of each iPhone model is currently in use?

Tags: iphone, statistics

I want to know how many users there currently are for each iPhone model and in which countries each one is used.

For instance-

### World users for:

iPhone 8 = 411,912,030

iPhone X = 1,120,498,232

iPhone XR = 790,875,338

iPhone 11 = 429,938,274

iPhone 11Pro = 317,483,584

---

UK users for:

iPhone 8 = 1,912,030

iPhone X = 6,498,232

iPhone XR = 7,875,338

iPhone 11 = 9,938,274

iPhone 11Pro = 3,483,584

---

USA users for:

iPhone 8 = 13,912,030

iPhone X = 29,498,232

iPhone XR = 37,875,338

iPhone 11 = 49,938,274

iPhone 11Pro = 33,483,584

---

Australia users for:

iPhone 8 = 912,030

iPhone X = 1,498,232

iPhone XR = 2,875,338

iPhone 11 = 3,938,274

iPhone 11Pro = 4,483,584

Is there a way to find this information out?

Obviously I would like the data to update every now and then.

Comment: Where did you get the data you have?

Comment: It was just an example purely based on a very rough estimate without knowing much.

Comment: You have to **PAY** for this type of info.  It's available, just not for free.  https://www.statista.com/statistics/263445/global-smartphone-sales-by-operating-system-since-2009/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no publicly available data for this information. Apple doesn't (and is not obliged to) make this data public.

If you are an iOS app developer, you can integrate with one of the many analytics solutions available that can give you a *limited* idea about similar metrics, (but for users of your app).

You can also consider looking at a similar trend report from [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/trends/), one of the leading players in the business. This should help you get an idea about similar if not exact data that you are looking for.

The kind of data you are looking for is not something that's generally made available publicly, even if Apple, or some 3rd party company has access to it.

<sub>P.S.: No affiliation whatsoever with Mixpanel.</sub>

Comment: It does help a little